# Trying to understand a line in latex.ltx (regarding \string, \escapechar and \csname in the definition of \newif)

Tags: tex-core, strings, csname

I'm trying to understand how exactly TeX parses documents, and with respect to that, the definition of `\newif` confuses me quite a lot (in `latex.ltx`, line 929ff):

```
\def\newif#1{%
  \count@\escapechar \escapechar\m@ne
    \let#1\iffalse
    \@if#1\iftrue
    \@if#1\iffalse
  \escapechar\count@}
\def\@if#1#2{%
  \expandafter\def\csname\expandafter\@gobbletwo\string#1%
      \expandafter\@gobbletwo\string#2\endcsname
          {\let#1#2}}
```

I understand what this definition *does* (i.e. `\newif\iffoo` introduces three macros `\iffoo`, `\foofalse` and `\footrue`), but I don't understand *why it works*. Here's how I understand this code:

- `\newif\iffoo` first stores the current escape character in `\count@` and temporarily redefines it to `-1`. This is probably the crux of the issue, but it's unclear to me how exactly that affects further parsing.
- We define `\iffoo` to be `\iffalse`. Apparently the redefining of `\escapechar` has no effect here yet. So far this makes sense, since (I guess) the "definition" of `\newif` and the argument `\iffoo` have already been tokenized before the `\escapechar`-stuff is expanded(?).
- Now the weird stuff that `\@if` does comes into play. We do `\@if\iffoo\iftrue`, which does the `\csname`-stuff. And here's where I don't understand how this works. I read this as:

  - `\expandafter\def\csname\expandafter\@gobbletwo\string#1\expandafter\@gobbletwo\string#2\endcsname` expands to
  - `\def[\csname\@gobbletwo[\string\iffoo]\@gobbletwo[\string\iftrue]\endcsname]` (where by the square brackets I mean *the evaluation of*).
  - According to the TeXbook, `\string` turns a control sequence into its constituent characters as individual tokens, including the escape character, all with category code 12. So `\string\iffoo` should turn into $\backslash_{12}i_{12}f_{12}f_{12}o_{12}o_{12}$. But this would result in `\csname ffooftrue\endcsname` rather than `\csname footrue\endcsname`.

Quote TeX book:

> Although control sequences are treated as single objects, TEX does provide a way to break them into lists of character tokens: If you write `\string\cs`, where `\cs`is any control sequence, you get the list of characters for that control sequence’s name. For example, `\string\TeX` produces four tokens: $\backslash_{12},T_{12},e_{12},X_{12}$. Each character in this token list automatically gets category code 12 (“other”), including the backslash that `\string` inserts to represent an escape character. However, category 10 will be assigned to the character ‘ ’ (blank space) if a space character somehow sneaks into the name of a control sequence.

So I guess my question is: Is the claim from the TeX book quote above simplified? Then how exactly does the current value of `\escapechar` impact the expansion of `\string`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\escapechar` setting means that `\string\foo`  is `foo` not `\foo` (no backslash) this means that the `\gobbletwo` gobbles `if` not `\i` when applied to `\string\ifzzz`

The texbook quote is assuming the default value of `\escapechar` when it says that a `\backslash_{12}` will be inserted.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, `\string` will only insert an escape character at all, if `\escapechar` is >-1, and if it is defined, it will insert *that* character with category code 12 - *independent* of which escape character was used when `\foo`was tokenized?

Comment: @DennisMüller yes there may have been no escape character at al it could have been made by `\csname foo \endcsname`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - thank you :)

Comment: @DennisMüller  Incidentally if you compare with the version of \newif in plain tex you will see that this form is latex only, did it that way to save a few tens of byes. We were _really_ short of space at the time:-)

Answer (score 4):

The command `\string<token>` works in two different ways:

- if `<token>` is a character token, the same character with category code 12 is delivered (but 10 is used if `<token>` is an explicit space token);
- otherwise `<token>` is a control sequence and in this case the *name* of the control sequence is delivered preceded by the character with code `\escapechar`; all characters so produced will have category code 12, except for spaces that retain their usual category code 10; however, if `\escapechar` has negative value or beyond 255 (`0x1FFFFF` for Unicode engines such as `xetex` or `luatex`), no character will be prepended.

Thus, when `\escapechar` is −1, the result of `\string\foo` will be `foo` (all characters having category code 12).

This is completely independent of the current character having category code 0. So, if you have

```
\catcode`@=0
@string@foo
```

and all other settings are standard, the delivered string of characters will be

```
\foo
```

because the default value for `\escapechar` is 92, as set by TeX at startup. This is witnessed by the following interactive session

```
> tex -ini '\catcode`{=1\catcode`}=2\message{\the\escapechar}'
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019) (INITEX)
92
```

However, nobody can know what's the value of `\escapechar` when `\newif` is called. Since one is expected to do `\newif\iffoo`, the macro needs to strip the *possible* `\escapechar` from the output of `\string\iffoo` in order to be able to define `\footrue` and `\foofalse`.

For instance, when reading `.fd` files, LaTeX enters a state where `\escapechar` is set to −1, so the backslash will not be inserted when using `\string` (it's not the only place). So the safest strategy is to temporarily set `\escapechar` to a known value and restore the value it had afterwards. Therefore, the current value is stored in `\count@` (note that `\escapechar` is an internal integer register), to be restored at the end of the job.

Setting the (temporary) value to 92 would require to use `\@gobblethree` (which is not defined in the kernel), so it's simpler to set it to −1 and use `\@gobbletwo`.

This could be done in a different way without storing the value in a counter, which might even be more preferable because `\count@` is not affected.

```latex
\def\newif#1{%
  \let#1\iffalse
  \@if#1\iftrue
  \@if#1\iffalse
}
\def\@if#1#2{%
  \begingroup\escapechar=\m@ne\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\def
    \csname\expandafter\@gobbletwo\string#1\expandafter\@gobbletwo\string#2\endcsname
    {\let#1#2}%
}
```

How does it work? The value of `\escapechar` is changed inside a group and will be restored as soon as the group ends. However, `\expandafter` pokes after `\endgroup` *before* the group ends so the token from `\csname` is formed when `\escapechar` to −1; `\endgroup` will restore the previous value of `\escapechar` and the `\def` will be performed.

An important difference from the similar macro in plain TeX is that LaTeX performs ***no*** check whether the argument to `\newif` is a control sequence whose name begins with `if`.

Answer (score 3):

The quote you reproduced is indeed simplified, but further on the same page (40), the TeXbook reads:

> In the examples so far, `\string` has converted control sequences into lists of tokens that begin with \<sub>12</sub>. But this backslash token isn't really hardwired into TeX; there's a parameter called `\escapechar` that specifies what character should be used when control sequences are output as text. The value of `\escapechar` is normally TeX's internal code for backslash, but it can be changed if another convention is desired.

Anyway, when you want to be sure, better also check later chapters such as the three *Summary of ... Mode* chapters at the end of the book. In this case, in chapter 20, *Definitions (also called Macros):*

> `\string`〈token〉. TeX first reads the 〈token〉 without expansion. If a control sequence token appears, its `\string` expansion consists of the control sequence name (including `\escapechar` as an escape character, if the control sequence isn't simply an active character). Otherwise the 〈token〉 is a character token, and its character code is retained as the expanded result.

Also, according to page 308, the omission of the escape char in Knuth's TeX when using `\string` happens if, and only if `\escapechar` is outside the [0,255] range:

> There is, however, another solution: If TeX's `\escapechar` parameter—which will be explained in one of the next dangerous bends—is negative or greater than 255, then `\string\\` works.

(the objective is to output a single backslash character token with category code 12).

Comment: Ah, so the escape character used for expanding `\string\foo` really *does* have nothing to do with the one used when `\foo` was originally tokenized- that was what confused me. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, when a control sequence is tokenized, TeX doesn't store the catcode-0 character used in the input; it only stores the rest of the control sequence name. When you use `\string` to expand to the name, `\escapechar` is only used for this output (a “prettyfying” parameter, sort of).